# Broken family, what resources does Judaism offer in books, teaching, old and contemporary about incorporating loving parent archetypes?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chinuch-education, family-members

Both mother and father were entirely demonstrative of negative aspects only. Would like to utilize Judaic teachings, perhaps in a contemporary orthodox-oriented book that's very well written and compassionate, drawing both on Mikra, Kabbalah but also on psychology, to incorporate and adopt within positive parents, this in order to heal and move on. Thoughts on this appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a parenting book? (i.e., a book geared towards parents to teach them how to be positive parents?)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Lonely-Man-Faith-Joseph-Soloveitchik/dp/0385514085/

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are asking I would highly recommend *[Positive Parenting](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066448.html)* by Rabbi Abraham J. Twerski, M.D. zt"l and Ursula Schwartz, Ph.D. Not only does it give the Torah perspective but also the deep-rooted psychological angle from two leading pyschologists.

The blurb there reads as follows:

> Rabbi Abraham J. Twerski, M.D. and Ursula Schwartz, Ph.D. are outstanding mental health practitioners. In this practical book they say, "Let's concentrate on how to do things right, and how the Torah and Jewish tradition counsel us to raise our children." This book belongs at the top of the Jewish reading list of every parent, teacher, or person who deals with parents and children.